# How do optimisers adapt to custom learning rates?

Tags: keras

I'm having difficulty in understanding how an `Optimiser` uses custom learning rates defined by a `LearningRateScheduler`. Looking at the source for `SGD`, the parameters seem to be affected by its own parameters only (e.g., `self.lr`) only:

```py
def get_updates(self, loss, params):
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
    self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

    lr = self.lr
    if self.initial_decay > 0:
        lr *= (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations,
                                              K.dtype(self.decay))))
    # momentum
    shapes = [K.int_shape(p) for p in params]
    moments = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
    self.weights = [self.iterations] + moments
    for p, g, m in zip(params, grads, moments):
        v = self.momentum * m - lr * g  # velocity
        self.updates.append(K.update(m, v))

        if self.nesterov:
            new_p = p + self.momentum * v - lr * g
        else:
            new_p = p + v
    ...
```

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L172

If `fit_generator` was called using:

```py
def step_decay(epoch):
    initial_lrate = 0.01
    drop = 0.5
    epochs_drop = 10.0
    lrate = initial_lrate * math.pow(drop, math.floor((1+epoch)/epochs_drop))
    return lrate

lr_scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
model.fit_generator(
    ...
    callbacks=[lr_scheduler],
    ...)
```

is the original learning rate used for initialising the optimiser overridden somehow? It seems to be to a certain extent. I've tried the following printer:

```py
class LearningRatePrinter(Callback):
    def init(self):
        super(LearningRatePrinter, self).init()

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        print('lr:', sess.run(optimizer.lr))

lr_printer = LearningRatePrinter()
```

and call `fit_generator()` with `callbacks=[lr_scheduler, lr_printer,]`. What I get is `lr: 0.01` for each epoch. Sure, `lr_printer` prints the member variable `lr`, but how is the `lr_scheduler` custom learning rate value used at all? There's no sign that it's actually being used.

Comment: Are you sure you're printing the correct variables? Your code works fine for me. `lr: 0.005` is printed after epoch 10 and `lr: 0.0025` after epoch 20, etc.

Comment: What if you change `sess.run(optimizer.lr)` into `K.eval(self.model.optimizer.lr)`?

Comment: The learning rate is updated [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L617) in the callback.

Comment: @Yu-Yang `K.eval(self.model.optimizer.lr)` did it. Thanks!